# Find the most repeated value of a property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my data, every node, has property "w" that has numeric values. I want to find out which value of "w" is used most often in the whole data. How can I do that? I use cypher for query.

Answer (score 2):

```
START n=node(*)
RETURN DISTINCT n.w
ORDER BY n.w DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This Cypher query returns the highest value of property "w". Please consult the [cypher cheat sheet](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/) if you want more info.

Comment: @mina, please approve if this answer helped you.

Comment: wait, how is that query returning the most frequent value of property w??